# bash script to rewrite numbers sequentially

Tags: bash, sed, sequence

I'd like to 're-sequence' some variable assignment values that are within a large BASH script I'm writing. At present, I have to do this manually, and it's quite time-consuming. ;)

e.g.:

```
(some code here)
ab=0
(and some here too)
   ab=3
(more code here)
cd=2; ab=1
(more code here)
     ab=2
```

What I'd like to do is run a command that can re-order the assignment values of 'ab' so we get:

```
(some code here)
ab=0
(and some here too)
   ab=1
(more code here)
cd=2; ab=2
(more code here)
     ab=3
```

The indentations exist as these usually form part of a code block, like an 'if' or 'for' block.

The variable name will always be the same. The first occurrence in the script should be made a zero. I thought if something (like sed) could search for 'ab=' followed by an integer, then change that integer according to an incrementing value, this would be perfect.

Hoping someone out there may know of something that can do this already. I use 'Kate' for my BASH editing.

Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: If this involves actually parsing bash scripts, it's going to be painful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ # can also use: perl -pe 's/\bab=\K\d+/$i++/ge' file
$ perl -pe 's/(\bab=)\d+/$1.$i++/ge' file
(some code here)
ab=0
(and some here too)
   ab=1
(more code here)
cd=2; ab=2
(more code here)
     ab=3
```

- `(\bab=)\d+` match `ab=` and one or more digits. `\b` is word boundary marker so that words like `dab=4` doesn't match
- The `e` modifier allows to use Perl code in replacement section
- `$1.$i++` is string concatenation of `ab=` and value of `$i` (which is `0` by default) Then `$i` gets incremented
- Use `perl -i -pe` for inplace editing

Comment: Thanks @Sundeep, I've been using your perl command and it works flawlessly. :)

Answer (score 1):

@teracoy:@try:

```
awk '/ab=/{sub(/ab=[0-9]+/,"ab="i++);print;next} 1'  Input_file
```

Comment: `;print;next` can be removed as every line is anyway printed by `1`... also, `gsub` if there are multiple matches in a line

Comment: @Sundeep `gsub()` would only increment `i` once for the whole line, you'd need some kind of loop of `sub()` calls to increment `i` multiple times but that's non-trivial.

Comment: @EdMorton didn't know that, thanks.. just assumed it :-/

Answer (score 1):

WIth GNU awk for multi-char RS, RT, and gensub():

```
$ awk -v RS='\\<ab=[0-9]+' '{ORS=gensub(/[0-9]+/,i++,1,RT)}1' file
(some code here)
ab=0
(and some here too)
   ab=1
(more code here)
cd=2; ab=2
(more code here)
     ab=3
```

Use `awk -i inplace ...` for inplace editing if desired.

Comment: Please advise what flavour of awk allows for the -i option as inplace as gawk seems to say it is includefile?

Comment: gawk - in gawk with the arguments `-i inplace`, unlike in sed `-i` doesn't mean `inplace`, instead `-i` means `include` and `inplace` is the extension you're telling it to include. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Extension-Sample-Inplace